# Error in the "rowkey" attribute of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Since I already meant that my English can be very bad so, I'm sorry.
I am new to JSF and am having trouble with the `rowkey` attribute of the `p:dataTable`. It simply can not identify the row ID because it can not find the "var" that I put in my DataTable. follow the code below:

```
    <p:dataTable var="categorias" value="#
    {categoriaController.dao.listaCategorias}" selection="#
    {categoriaController.dao.selectedCategoria}" selectionMode="single" 
    rowKey="#{categorias.idCategoria}">
          <p:column headertext"nome da categoria">..............
    </p:datatable/>
```

Before even starting the server to test the IDE already tells me that in the line of "rowkey" he could not find the reference I put, I searched a lot but could not find anyone with the same error as I.
What should I do? Did I do something wrong? How did I make this mistake?

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.2 on JSF 2.2 (version info and implementation should be proviced)

Comment: Can you added your bean code as well how you creating `listaCategorias`

Comment: i think you  need to access the rowkey value using managedbean. 
rowKey="#{managedbean.categorias.idCategoria}"

Comment: @v0ld3m0rt Not really, because in PrimeFaces Docs and in Showcase it shows that you should use your `var` as a reference to get the ID. And I already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to make some assumptions since you have not provided your code for the elements in the `List listaCategorias`, but assuming that those elements have an attribute `idCategoria` and this attribute is unique for each element, `rowKey` needs to be a `String` or something that can be implicitly cast to a `String`. The Class for the elements must have a public `getIdCategoria()` method that returns a unique `String` object or something that can be implicitly cast to a `String`.

If you examine the request that is sent when an editable DataTable is submitted, you'll see the rowKey value for each changed element, allowing the server side code to determine which object in the model the element refers to.

Answer (score 0):

@snakedog First of all I want to say that my English is bad, so I'm sorry.

In the list "Categories" there is a public getId () and that returns a unique id, this id that it returns is of type long because in the database the column of this id is of type bigint.

I have to make it return a String for the rowKey to work? The problem is that rowKey can not get the reference to the "Category" Object that I did in the var attribute, and I also noticed that when I open the tag `<p:datatable>` and now I close (thus `<p: datatable ... />`) the rowKey can get the var reference, but if I open the tag (thus `<p:datatable> ... </p:datatable>`) the rowKey can no longer pick up the var reference.